# Unidentified index, variable, and permission denied

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I am using opencart 2.0 and everything works fine until I installed an extension. I already have a theme previously installed but after inserting the extension several errors appeared. I am not familiar with Php so I am having a hard time figuring things out.

I did some research and some says it may be a version defect but everything I used are precisely for opencart 2.0, the other one says that it may be that the config file was not set properly,but I didn't move my site from local to live yet so everything in my config file are all correct. 
And he last one is to insert isset, I am not sure about this but from the looks of the code I think everything was set properly.

This are the errors

```html
Notice:  Undefined index: company_id_display in C:\wamp\www\quick3\catalog\view\theme\default\template\d_quickcheckout\payment_address.tpl on line 85
2015-03-21 11:22:23 - PHP Notice:  Undefined index: company_id_required in C:\wamp\www\quick3\catalog\view\theme\default\template\d_quickcheckout\payment_address.tpl on line 86
2015-03-21 11:22:23 - PHP Notice:  Undefined index: tax_id_display in C:\wamp\www\quick3\catalog\view\theme\default\template\d_quickcheckout\payment_address.tpl on line 87
2015-03-21 11:22:23 - PHP Notice:  Undefined index: tax_id_required in C:\wamp\www\quick3\catalog\view\theme\default\template\d_quickcheckout\payment_address.tpl on line 88
2015-03-21 11:35:31 - PHP Notice:  Undefined index: company_id_display in C:\wamp\www\quick3\catalog\view\theme\default\template\d_quickcheckout\payment_address.tpl on line 85
2015-03-21 11:35:31 - PHP Notice:  Undefined index: company_id_required in C:\wamp\www\quick3\catalog\view\theme\default\template\d_quickcheckout\payment_address.tpl on line 86
2015-03-21 11:35:31 - PHP Notice:  Undefined index: tax_id_display in C:\wamp\www\quick3\catalog\view\theme\default\template\d_quickcheckout\payment_address.tpl on line 87
2015-03-21 11:35:31 - PHP Notice:  Undefined index: tax_id_required in C:\wamp\www\quick3\catalog\view\theme\default\template\d_quickcheckout\payment_address.tpl on line 88
2015-03-21 11:38:17 - PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: template in C:\wamp\www\quick3\catalog\controller\module\d_quickcheckout.php on line 644
2015-03-21 11:38:17 - PHP Warning:  require(C:\wamp\www\quick3\catalog\view\theme): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\quick3\vqmod\vqcache\vq2-system_engine_loader.php on line 37
2015-03-21 11:52:09 - PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: template in C:\wamp\www\quick3\catalog\controller\module\d_quickcheckout.php on line 644
2015-03-21 11:52:09 - PHP Warning:  require(C:\wamp\www\quick3\catalog\view\theme): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\quick3\vqmod\vqcache\vq2-system_engine_loader.php on line 37
2015-03-21 20:09:29 - PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: template in C:\wamp\www\quick3\catalog\controller\module\d_quickcheckout.php on line 644
2015-03-21 20:09:29 - PHP Warning:  require(C:\wamp\www\quick3\catalog\view\theme): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\quick3\vqmod\vqcache\vq2-system_engine_loader.php on line 37
2015-03-25 7:35:52 - PHP Notice:  unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 31 bytes in C:\wamp\www\quick3\system\library\cart.php on line 23
2015-03-25 7:38:12 - PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: text_qty in C:\wamp\www\quick3\vqmod\vqcache\vq2-catalog_view_theme_marketshop_template_product_product.tpl on line 294
2015-03-25 7:38:27 - PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: template in C:\wamp\www\quick3\catalog\controller\module\d_quickcheckout.php on line 644
2015-03-25 7:38:27 - PHP Warning:  require(C:\wamp\www\quick3\catalog\view\theme): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\quick3\vqmod\vqcache\vq2-system_engine_loader.php on line 37
2015-03-25 8:16:12 - PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: template in C:\wamp\www\quick3\catalog\controller\module\d_quickcheckout.php on line 644
2015-03-25 8:16:12 - PHP Warning:  require(C:\wamp\www\quick3\catalog\view\theme): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\quick3\vqmod\vqcache\vq2-system_engine_loader.php on line 37
2015-03-25 8:35:20 - PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: template in C:\wamp\www\quick3\catalog\controller\module\d_quickcheckout.php on line 644
2015-03-25 8:35:20 - PHP Warning:  require(C:\wamp\www\quick3\catalog\view\theme): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\quick3\vqmod\vqcache\vq2-system_engine_loader.php on line 37
2015-03-25 10:08:01 - PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: template in C:\wamp\www\quick3\catalog\controller\module\d_quickcheckout.php on line 644
2015-03-25 10:08:01 - PHP Warning:  require(C:\wamp\www\quick3\catalog\view\theme): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\quick3\vqmod\vqcache\vq2-system_engine_loader.php on line 37
```

And this are the codes

**d_quickcheckout.php on line 644**

```html
return $this->load->view($template, $data);
```

**payment_address.tpl line 85,86,87,and 88**

```js
customer_group[<?php echo $customer_group['customer_group_id']; ?>]['company_id_display'] = '<?php echo $customer_group['company_id_display']; ?>';
  customer_group[<?php echo $customer_group['customer_group_id']; ?>]['company_id_required'] = '<?php echo $customer_group['company_id_required']; ?>';
  customer_group[<?php echo $customer_group['customer_group_id']; ?>]['tax_id_display'] = '<?php echo $customer_group['tax_id_display']; ?>';
  customer_group[<?php echo $customer_group['customer_group_id']; ?>]['tax_id_required'] = '<?php echo $customer_group['tax_id_required']; ?>';
```

**vq2-system_engine_loader.php on line 37**

```js
require(VQMod::modCheck($file));
```

When I checked my vqmod log this appears

```html
---------- Date: 2015-03-21 11:20:05 ~ IP : ::1 ----------
REQUEST URI : /quick3/admin/index.php?route=common/dashboard&token=5f0179921a263de04c1c92819780f622
MOD DETAILS:
   modFile   : C:\wamp\www\quick3\vqmod/xml/extension_name.xml
   id        : EXTENSION
   version   : 2.0.0.0
   vqmver    : 2.2.1
   author    : dreamvention.com
VQModObject::parseMods - Could not resolve path for [catalog/view/theme/default/template/payment/pp_pro_uk.tpl] (SKIPPED)

----------------------------------------------------------------------


---------- Date: 2015-03-21 11:35:16 ~ IP : ::1 ----------
REQUEST URI : /quick3/admin/index.php?route=extension/module&token=5f0179921a263de04c1c92819780f622
MOD DETAILS:
   modFile   : C:\wamp\www\quick3\vqmod/xml/extension_name.xml
   id        : EXTENSION
   version   : 2.0.0.0
   vqmver    : 2.2.1
   author    : dreamvention.com
VQModObject::parseMods - Could not resolve path for [catalog/view/theme/default/template/payment/pp_pro_uk.tpl] (SKIPPED)

MOD DETAILS:
   modFile   : C:\wamp\www\quick3\vqmod/xml/theme_name.xml
   id        : Theme
   version   : 2.0
   vqmver    : 2.X
   author    : HarnishDesign.net
VQModObject::parseMods - Could not resolve path for [catalog/controller/module/product.php] (SKIPPED)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Did the extension overwrite any files? Also, are you sure it was compatible with OpenCart 2.0 ? The company_id_required & tax_id_required errors look like bugs I used to come across all the time in opencart 1.5.*

Comment: Yes I made sure that all the versions are compatible. My opencart is 2.0.1.1, and my theme is specifically for 2.0.1.1 and my extension is compatible with 2.0.1.1.
When I moved the files it didn't overwrite anything

Comment: Then my suggestion is to check the vqmod log to see if any changes from the vqmod are failing to apply. Did the theme overwrite any php (many of the modern themes do) especially any of the controller files? This may cause the VQMOD changes not to work if it can't find a certain line.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question and added the vqmod log file

Comment: I see those log entries are from several days ago (21/March). Are there any for today? (i.e. from a run that you just did that threw the php errors)

Comment: @colmde I reinstalled it, now it's showing two errors 

---2015-03-27 4:35:29 - PHP Notice:  Undefined index: country_id in C:\wamp\www\quick8\system\library\tax.php on line 17
2015-03-27 4:35:29 - PHP Notice:  Undefined index: zone_id in C:\wamp\www\quick8\system\library\tax.php on line 17---

I would also like to add that when I installed the theme and the extension individually, both worked. But when I installed them together, the error appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in the code d_quickcheckout.php in line 641 this causes line 644 to look for a variable that has not been set.

Change $templatetemplate to $template in line 641.